# Use DISTINCT ON with empty n:n relations

Tags: sql, postgresql, relationship, distinct-on

I'm a new user of PostgreSQL, trying to use `DISTINCT ON` but I can't reach my goal.

Here's a brief sketch of my database :

- files with versioning
- fields with model (for form generation purpose)
- `n:n` relations between files' versions and fields

[image]

**I would like to retrieve a whole set of fields for a specified file's version.**
My problem is that we could have (and we'll) empty values, ie. **missing FileVersion_Field relations**. I'll try to give you an example bellow :

```
FileVersion                            Field                                
+----------------+---------+---------+ +----------+-------+---------------+ 
| id_fileversion | id_file | version | | id_field | value | id_fieldmodel | 
+----------------+---------+---------+ +----------+-------+---------------+ 
| 1              | 1       | 1       | | 1        | Smith | 1             | 
| 2              | 1       | 2       | | 2        | 20    | 2             | 
+----------------+---------+---------+ | 3        | 25    | 2             | 
                                       +----------+-------+---------------+

FileVersion_Field             FieldModel
+----------------+----------+ +---------------+------+
| id_fileversion | id_field | | id_fieldmodel | type |
+----------------+----------+ +---------------+------+
| 1              | 1        | | 1             | Name |
| 1              | 2        | | 2             | Age  |
| 2              | 3        | +---------------+------+
+----------------+----------+
```

In this example, I would like to get these results:

```
-- id_file=1 & version=1
Name | Smith
Age  | 20
```

```
-- id_file=1 & version=2
Name | 
Age  | 25
```

Here's what I've tried, which doesn't work :

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON(FieldModel.id_fieldmodel) *
FROM File
LEFT JOIN FileVersion ON File.id_file = FileVersion.id_file
LEFT JOIN FileVersion_Field ON FileVersion.id_fileversion = FileVersion_Field.id_fileversion
LEFT JOIN Field ON FileVersion_Field.id_field = Field.id_field
RIGHT JOIN FieldModel ON (Field.id_fieldmodel = FieldModel.id_fieldmodel OR FieldModel.id_fieldmodel IS NULL)
WHERE (FieldModel.id_fieldmodel IS NOT NULL AND FileVersion.version = 2 AND File.id_file = 1)
   OR (Field.id_fieldmodel IS NULL)
ORDER BY FieldModel.id_fieldmodel;
```

---

```sql
-- Sample Structure
CREATE TABLE File (
  id_file integer PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE FieldModel (
  id_fieldmodel integer PRIMARY KEY, type varchar(50));
CREATE TABLE FileVersion (
  id_fileversion integer PRIMARY KEY, 
  id_file integer, version integer, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_fileversion_file FOREIGN KEY(id_file) REFERENCES File(id_file));
CREATE TABLE Field (
  id_field integer PRIMARY KEY, 
  id_fieldmodel integer, 
  value varchar(255), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_field_fieldmodel FOREIGN KEY(id_fieldmodel) REFERENCES FieldModel(id_fieldmodel));
CREATE TABLE FileVersion_Field (
  id_fileversion integer, 
  id_field integer, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id_fileversion, id_field), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_fileversionfield_fileversion FOREIGN KEY(id_fileversion) REFERENCES FileVersion(id_fileversion), 
  CONSTRAINT fk_fileversionfield_field FOREIGN KEY(id_field) REFERENCES Field(id_field));

-- Sample Data
INSERT INTO File (id_file) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO FileVersion (id_fileversion, id_file, version) VALUES (1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2);
INSERT INTO FieldModel (id_fieldmodel, type) VALUES (1, 'Name'), (2, 'Age');
INSERT INTO Field (id_field, id_fieldmodel, value) VALUES (1, 1, 'Smith'), (2, 2, '20'), (3, 2, '25');
INSERT INTO FileVersion_Field (id_fileversion, id_field) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3);
```

Comment: How do you know that `name` goes with version 2 and not 1?

Comment: Field models are the 'base'. They goes with everything. Here no value was entered for `name` model in version 2, then I want an empty cell in my results.

Comment: . . Then why isn't it part of version 1 as well?

Comment: In my request ? I focused it on version 2, but I could use the same with version 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*7 years later, time to exorcize my daemons!*

I just needed to change my way of thinking.

1. First, we need the list of all used `FieldModel` for a `File`, whatever the version:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT(fm.id_fieldmodel), fm.type
FROM FieldModel fm
LEFT JOIN Field f ON fm.id_fieldmodel = f.id_fieldmodel
LEFT JOIN FileVersion_Field fvf ON f.id_field = fvf.id_field
LEFT JOIN FileVersion fv ON fv.id_fileversion = fvf.id_fileversion
WHERE fv.id_file = 1;

--  id_fieldmodel | type
-- ---------------+------
--              1 | Name
--              2 | Age
```

2. Now, we need the list of `Field` for the same `File`, but this time with a specified version:

```
SELECT f.id_fieldmodel, f.value
FROM FileVersion_Field fvv
JOIN FileVersion fv ON fv.id_fileversion = fvv.id_fileversion
JOIN Field f ON f.id_field = fvv.id_field
WHERE fv.id_file = 1 AND fv.version = 2;

--  id_fieldmodel | value
-- ---------------+-------
--              2 | 25
```

3. All that remains is to use a `LEFT JOIN` on both computed tables, by allowing `NULL` values in the fields:

```sql
SELECT fm.type, f.value
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT(fm.id_fieldmodel), fm.type
  FROM FieldModel fm
  LEFT JOIN Field f ON fm.id_fieldmodel = f.id_fieldmodel
  LEFT JOIN FileVersion_Field fvf ON f.id_field = fvf.id_field
  LEFT JOIN FileVersion fv ON fv.id_fileversion = fvf.id_fileversion
  WHERE fv.id_file = 1
) fm 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT f.id_fieldmodel, f.value
  FROM FileVersion_Field fvv
  JOIN FileVersion fv ON fv.id_fileversion = fvv.id_fileversion
  JOIN Field f ON f.id_field = fvv.id_field
  WHERE fv.id_file = 1 AND fv.version = 2
) f ON (f.id_fieldmodel = fm.id_fieldmodel OR f.id_fieldmodel IS NULL);

--  type | value
-- ------+-------
--  Name |
--  Age  | 25
```